# More convenient NSArray and NSDictionary access

Tags: objective-c

Note that this is merely an academic question.

In Ruby, you can access array and dictionary(hash) elements conveniently:

```
value = myHash['myKey']
```

In Objective C, you need a method call:

```
value = [myDict objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

How might one override some type of brackets or define a macro to bring the Objective C syntax closer to Ruby's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an update:

Starting with iOS 6 I guess, you CAN use such a syntax:

```
value = dictionary[@"key"];
```

This is equivalent to

```
value = [dictionary objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Moreover, if we're talking about NSMutableDictionary, you can add new objects into a dictionary like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
dictionary[@"a"] = @"A";
NSLog(@"%@",dictionary[@"a"]);
```

Comment: This is of course the correct answer now. As a side note, you can make anything (like NSFetchedResults for index paths) sub-scriptable by implementing subscript methods.

Comment: Actually, if I understood correctly, it should be equivalent to `objectForKeyedSubscript:` which states that is equivalent to `valueForKey:` . A small difference, but sometimes important. [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do requires a language feature called "operator overloading". Objective-C does not allow for operator overloading because the designers of the language felt that operator overloading was harmful more often than it was helpful.

C++ does allow for operator overloading, so one way to get the syntax you want is to wrap your collections in C++ classes and use those instead. To switch to Objective-C++, just change your implementation files' extensions from .m to .mm.

Personally, I would recommend against using C++ wrappers around collections because it will make your code harder for other Objective-C programmers to read and it will break some of the more advanced features of Xcode. For example, you will no longer be able to use the refactor tools, because Xcode will not be able to parse your code correctly.

Comment: It also unnecessarily complicates your code just to save a few keystrokes on array accesses. That is *such* a losing proposition.

Comment: Thanks Nathan.  I knew that people would recommend against it (and I am unlikely to use it for more than an example and discussion piece), which is why I marked it as academic.  I have overloaded operators like +, but how specifically would one overload brackets, parenthesis, or other matching pairs to accomplish a collection lookup shortcut.

Comment: @Peter-DeWeese, what you're trying to do for the bracket operator would look something like this:
`id operator[](int i) { return [collection objectAtIndex:i]; }`

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have told you why you can't do it - or how to work around it, but Objective-C is a verbose language - and using descriptive names is part of the **pleasure** of the language. Sure, you are typing a few more letters, but with code completion it's hardly any slower to write and you can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Personally I find the verbosity – especially bracket soup – to make it less readable overall.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Objective-C++, define C++ wrapper classes for NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary, and override operator, the array subscript operator.

Comment: Any tips on wrapping an objective c class in c++?  I found lots of resources for the opposite.

Comment: Hey! You said it was "merely an academic question," so I gave an academic answer. Just because you *can* do this doesn't mean that you *should*. If you prefer Ruby, then why not [use Ruby](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rubycocoa/)?

Comment: Tips? I'm rusty here... can you not create a constructor that allocates and initializes the wrapped object, and a destructor that releases it? It should be fine to have an ivar in your wrapper class that points to the Obj-C object, and you can use that to send it messages. Seems like a lot of work just to be able to do something in a non-standard way, though.

Comment: I'm interested in the language, hence the academic question and trying it out.  Thanks!